# linux file and directory permission

Tags: linux, permissions

```
1. drwxr-xr-x 10 tester test 100 Sep 8 09:30 hello
2. -rwsrwsrwt 2 tester test 100 Sep 8 09:35 program
```

I want to know the permissions of the folder "hello" and the file "program", the following is my interpretation, am i right?

1. About the directory “hello”, the tester user has read, write and execute permission, the test group and others have read and execute permission but no write permission.
2. About the file "program", the tester user, test group and others have full permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your `program` also has the `setuid`, `setguid` and `sticky` bits set.  Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) about what they mean.  Sticky bit use on executables is very rare these days and normally only on directories such as `/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

With unix directories x means access not execute, but yes for the directory "home":

- user "tester" can read the contents of the directory, change the contents of the directory and change into the directory via the cd command
- the group "test" may read the contents of the directory and change into the directory via the cd command
- every other user may the contents of the directory and change into the directory via the cd command

For the file "program":

- the user "tester", the group "test" and anybody else have the full set of rights and the programm will be executed under the uid of user "tester" (SUID-bit) and the group "test" (SGID-bit) and the sticky bit is also thrown in. This is not used on files any longer, only on directories like /tmp to prevent users from beeing able to delete some other users files.